# How do I query data using a column value as a comparison?

Tags: parse-platform

I'm looking to find a list of all results in my Parse database where column a< column b. So far the closest I've got is this (where Qty and QtyMax are columns A and B):

```
var query = new Parse.Query("Item");
query.lessThan("Qty",0); // In this example I'm passing in an int, 
                         // but I really want to pass in a reference 
                         // to a different column's value for the same row.
```

Return "all rows where Qty < QtyMax" is the desired query.

Any ideas how I'd do that?

Comment: Comparing two columns are not supported as I know.

Answer (score 0):

Try this (type Pointer might need to be changed to another type):

```
query.lessThan("Qty", {__type: "Pointer", className: "Item", objectId: 0});
```